# MSQL joins including two different DATE between condition

Tags: mysql

I have written the below query.

```
SELECT bmr_multi_price. * 
FROM bmr_multi_price
INNER JOIN bmr_rooms ON bmr_rooms.resort_id = bmr_multi_price.resort_id
AND bmr_rooms.id = bmr_multi_price.room_id
```

For this above query i have got the below result set.

[image]

But I wanted to include the below condition to achieve the above result.

```
WHERE ( '08/02/2013' BETWEEN bmr_multi_price.from_date AND bmr_multi_price.to_date ) OR ( '08/03/2013' BETWEEN bmr_multi_price.from_date AND bmr_multi_price.to_date )
```

Comment: And then? What happened then?

Comment: Did you have a question, or were you just giving a status report?

Comment: I guess he wants to cast to date?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, was in meeting ;).. I want to add the date between condition to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the query isn't returning expected results, the likely explanation is that you're comparing strings, and not dates.

The MySQL [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function is a convenient way to convert strings in a given format into a DATE value. I'm going to guess that string represents a date in mm/dd/yyyy format, based on the values returned in the resultset.

```
STR_TO_DATE('08/12/2013','%m/%d/%Y')
```

If those columns are defined as character, rather that DATE, then you can convert them as well:

```
STR_TO_DATE(bmr_multi_price.from_date,'%m/%d/%y')
```

MySQL provides a `DATE` datatype which makes working with dates much easier and (usually) much more efficient.

Comment: Thank you so much it works for me!!! and ih ave changed the date fields type from char to DATE